# Kubernetes deployment and replicaset keep reappearing

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeflow

First time Kubernetes user here.

I deployed a service using `kubectl -n my_namespace apply -f new_service.yaml`

It failed, with the pod showing `Warning -Back-off restarting failed container`

I am now trying to delete the failed objects and redeploy a fixed version. However, I have tried to delete the service, pod, deployment, and replicaset, but they all keep recreating themselves.

I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63344878/kubernetes-deployments-replicasets-are-recreated-after-deletion) but don't believe it applies since my deployment list:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
```

Any input appreciated!

Comment: do `kubectl -n my_namespace delete  -f new_service.yaml` and repeate for deployment. focus on deleting deployment  and service. The  pods, replica sets will get deleted

Comment: also, are you using tools like helm? for creating objects?

Comment: Well, yeah, the point of a replicaset is to make sure replicas are runnng.  I'd start by setting the replica count to 0..

Comment: @P.... ahh thank you so much, that seemed to do the trick. Yes, we use Helm and Argo, but I don't have much experience with them yet.

Comment: @P.... Could you post an answer? It would be more visible to the community.

Answer (score 5):

Posting this as Community wiki for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

**In a Kubernetes cluster**:

- if you delete Pods, but they are recreated again
  `there is a Kubernetes Deployment / StatefulSet / DaemonSet / job that recreates them`
  **delete a Deployment / StatefulSet / DaemonSet to delete those pods, check k8s jobs**
- if you delete a ReplicaSet, but it is recreated again
  `there is a Kubernetes Deployment that recreates it`
  **delete a Deployment to delete this replicaset**
- if you delete a Deployments / Services, etc., but they are recreated again
  `there is a deployment tool like ArgoCD / FluxCD / other tool that recreates them`
  **configure ArgoCD / FluxCD / other deployment tool to delete them**
- also check if Helm is used, run `helm list --all-namespaces` to list installed releases.

Thanks to @P....for comments.

Comment: Strangely enough this still isn't enough to delete my deployments. We do have Helm, but `helm ls` doesn't show any deployments that should be relevant. Is there a way to see what exactly created the deployment? 
Perhaps this? `manager: kube-controller-manager`

Comment: Ah almost immediately after posting this I found a helm-CD-pipeline that was the culprit.